# SVG animation on scroll once

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animations

Hi everyone I can program, and I saw a few weeks ago, that SVG animations are pretty useful!

Now my question:
I want to animate text like this website: https://weaintplastic.com/ I do not want the other things, just the Animation! I tried a lot of things, Exported via Illustrator a svg but it did not worked out. I do not want to use, any tool from github!

My assumption is:

I have to animate any letter in a Word (like the website), such that I have to know the paths from the svg! But this makes problem! How can I get a animation like this? Lets assume I want the word for ABOUT ME for example, how can I achieve CSS and JS which does the job for any svg if I have the path, or do I have to do for every Letter an own CSS and JS?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 27.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 315 45" style="enable-background:new 0 0 315 45;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;}
</style>
<g>
    <path d="M78.55,26.83l-2,5.75h-2.57l6.53-18.3h2.99l6.56,18.3h-2.65l-2.05-5.75H78.55z M84.85,24.98l-1.88-5.27
        c-0.43-1.19-0.71-2.28-1-3.34h-0.06c-0.29,1.09-0.6,2.2-0.97,3.31l-1.88,5.29H84.85z"/>
    <path d="M92.61,32.58c0.06-0.9,0.11-2.23,0.11-3.39V13.31h2.48v8.25h0.06c0.88-1.47,2.48-2.42,4.71-2.42c3.42,0,5.85,2.71,5.82,6.7
        c0,4.7-3.11,7.03-6.19,7.03c-2,0-3.59-0.73-4.62-2.47h-0.09l-0.11,2.17H92.61z M95.2,27.32c0,0.3,0.06,0.6,0.11,0.87
        c0.48,1.66,1.94,2.8,3.76,2.8c2.62,0,4.19-2.04,4.19-5.05c0-2.63-1.43-4.89-4.11-4.89c-1.71,0-3.31,1.11-3.82,2.93
        c-0.06,0.27-0.14,0.6-0.14,0.98V27.32z"/>
    <path d="M121.44,25.9c0,4.86-3.54,6.98-6.87,6.98c-3.74,0-6.62-2.61-6.62-6.76c0-4.4,3.02-6.98,6.84-6.98
        C118.75,19.15,121.44,21.89,121.44,25.9z M110.48,26.04c0,2.88,1.74,5.05,4.19,5.05c2.4,0,4.19-2.14,4.19-5.1
        c0-2.23-1.17-5.05-4.14-5.05S110.48,23.54,110.48,26.04z"/>
    <path d="M136.15,29c0,1.36,0.03,2.55,0.11,3.58h-2.22l-0.14-2.14h-0.06c-0.66,1.06-2.11,2.44-4.56,2.44
        c-2.17,0-4.76-1.14-4.76-5.75v-7.68h2.51v7.27c0,2.5,0.8,4.18,3.08,4.18c1.68,0,2.85-1.11,3.31-2.17c0.14-0.35,0.23-0.79,0.23-1.22
        v-8.06h2.51V29z"/>
    <path d="M143.33,15.67v3.77h3.59v1.82h-3.59v7.09c0,1.63,0.48,2.55,1.88,2.55c0.66,0,1.14-0.08,1.45-0.16l0.11,1.79
        c-0.48,0.19-1.25,0.33-2.22,0.33c-1.17,0-2.11-0.35-2.71-1c-0.71-0.71-0.97-1.87-0.97-3.42v-7.17h-2.14v-1.82h2.14v-3.15
        L143.33,15.67z"/>
    <path d="M172.08,24.55c-0.14-2.55-0.31-5.62-0.29-7.9h-0.09c-0.66,2.14-1.45,4.42-2.42,6.95l-3.39,8.88h-1.88l-3.11-8.71
        c-0.91-2.58-1.68-4.94-2.22-7.11h-0.06c-0.06,2.28-0.2,5.35-0.37,8.09l-0.51,7.84h-2.37l1.34-18.3h3.17l3.28,8.85
        c0.8,2.25,1.46,4.26,1.94,6.16h0.09c0.48-1.85,1.17-3.86,2.02-6.16l3.42-8.85h3.17l1.2,18.3h-2.42L172.08,24.55z"/>
    <path d="M188.76,24h-7.47v6.6h8.33v1.98H178.8v-18.3h10.38v1.98h-7.9v5.78h7.47V24z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <rect x="54.72" y="8.99" class="st0" width="69.62" height="7.96"/>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I tried figma and svgator, and so on, but this is not useful, since I want to DO the ANIMATION WHEN I SCROLL on the section. (Once like the website).
I am sorry if my question is not Perfect, I tried my best to be precise as possible, and searched first on the Forum before I asked.

Comment: You could look at how this does it: http://svg-wow.org/text-effects/text-effects.xhtml

Comment: Okay thank you for your fast reply, but since I saw it, it does not fulfill my purpose I think, since it has to be filled out, or am i missing something?

Comment: It shows you various mechanisms that can animate text. Adapt the concepts therein to your particular purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The technique has to be a combination with [`SVGGeometryElement.getTotalLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getTotalLength), [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray), [`stroke-dashoffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset), and the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

The example you provided has a lot more complex SVG elements than your own example. If you inspect the SVG you'll see that each letter consists of 1 or more `<polygon>` elements that are being animated. Being that your own SVG is a bit simpler I've built the example below on it.

First thing that is important is that the animation in the example animates the `stroke` property of each polygon. They do that by calculating the entire length of each path and setting both the `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` properties with that total calculated path length. This will *push* the stroke out of the svg to be invisible, setting up the animation. (Each path has a different length, so setting the properties manually is a tedious job, let JS do it).

Then use the Intersection Observer API to determine *when* certain elements come into view. In this case I've chosen to watch for whole sections to come into view. Whenever a section enters the viewport, it will add an `animate` class to the section. In CSS I've defined that the class will trigger an animation that will change the `stroke-dashoffset` property. This will cause the stroke to animate back into the SVG.

```js
const paths = document.querySelectorAll('svg path');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

paths.forEach((path, index) => {
  const length = path.getTotalLength();
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = `${length}px`;
  path.style.strokeDasharray = `${length}px`;
  path.style.animationDelay = `${index * 250}ms`;
});

const onInterSection = (entries, observer) => {
  for (const { isIntersecting, target } of entries) {
    if (isIntersecting) {
      target.classList.add('animate');
      observer.unobserve(target);
    }
  }
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(onInterSection);

for (const section of sections) {
  observer.observe(section);
}
```

```css
.st0 {
  fill: none;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 75vh;
}

section:first-of-type {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
}

section.animate path {
  animation: letter 2s 1s forwards ease-out;
}

@keyframes letter {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <span>Scroll down to animation</span>
</section>

<section>
  <span>A bit further</span>
</section>

<section>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 315 45" style="enable-background:new 0 0 315 45;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path d="M78.55,26.83l-2,5.75h-2.57l6.53-18.3h2.99l6.56,18.3h-2.65l-2.05-5.75H78.55z M84.85,24.98l-1.88-5.27
        c-0.43-1.19-0.71-2.28-1-3.34h-0.06c-0.29,1.09-0.6,2.2-0.97,3.31l-1.88,5.29H84.85z"/>
    <path d="M92.61,32.58c0.06-0.9,0.11-2.23,0.11-3.39V13.31h2.48v8.25h0.06c0.88-1.47,2.48-2.42,4.71-2.42c3.42,0,5.85,2.71,5.82,6.7
        c0,4.7-3.11,7.03-6.19,7.03c-2,0-3.59-0.73-4.62-2.47h-0.09l-0.11,2.17H92.61z M95.2,27.32c0,0.3,0.06,0.6,0.11,0.87
        c0.48,1.66,1.94,2.8,3.76,2.8c2.62,0,4.19-2.04,4.19-5.05c0-2.63-1.43-4.89-4.11-4.89c-1.71,0-3.31,1.11-3.82,2.93
        c-0.06,0.27-0.14,0.6-0.14,0.98V27.32z"/>
    <path d="M121.44,25.9c0,4.86-3.54,6.98-6.87,6.98c-3.74,0-6.62-2.61-6.62-6.76c0-4.4,3.02-6.98,6.84-6.98
        C118.75,19.15,121.44,21.89,121.44,25.9z M110.48,26.04c0,2.88,1.74,5.05,4.19,5.05c2.4,0,4.19-2.14,4.19-5.1
        c0-2.23-1.17-5.05-4.14-5.05S110.48,23.54,110.48,26.04z"/>
    <path d="M136.15,29c0,1.36,0.03,2.55,0.11,3.58h-2.22l-0.14-2.14h-0.06c-0.66,1.06-2.11,2.44-4.56,2.44
        c-2.17,0-4.76-1.14-4.76-5.75v-7.68h2.51v7.27c0,2.5,0.8,4.18,3.08,4.18c1.68,0,2.85-1.11,3.31-2.17c0.14-0.35,0.23-0.79,0.23-1.22
        v-8.06h2.51V29z"/>
    <path d="M143.33,15.67v3.77h3.59v1.82h-3.59v7.09c0,1.63,0.48,2.55,1.88,2.55c0.66,0,1.14-0.08,1.45-0.16l0.11,1.79
        c-0.48,0.19-1.25,0.33-2.22,0.33c-1.17,0-2.11-0.35-2.71-1c-0.71-0.71-0.97-1.87-0.97-3.42v-7.17h-2.14v-1.82h2.14v-3.15
        L143.33,15.67z"/>
    <path d="M172.08,24.55c-0.14-2.55-0.31-5.62-0.29-7.9h-0.09c-0.66,2.14-1.45,4.42-2.42,6.95l-3.39,8.88h-1.88l-3.11-8.71
        c-0.91-2.58-1.68-4.94-2.22-7.11h-0.06c-0.06,2.28-0.2,5.35-0.37,8.09l-0.51,7.84h-2.37l1.34-18.3h3.17l3.28,8.85
        c0.8,2.25,1.46,4.26,1.94,6.16h0.09c0.48-1.85,1.17-3.86,2.02-6.16l3.42-8.85h3.17l1.2,18.3h-2.42L172.08,24.55z"/>
    <path d="M188.76,24h-7.47v6.6h8.33v1.98H178.8v-18.3h10.38v1.98h-7.9v5.78h7.47V24z"/>
    <rect x="54.72" y="8.99" class="st0" width="69.62" height="7.96"/>
</svg>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats a perfect answer!! I will try it right now!